# Amazon EC2 ssh timeout

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS services. I created an EC2 instance of Ubuntu and I was able to connect to it. I was able to run TeamCity and Rails server on the instance and things were fine. I created an image of the instance and now I can not ssh back.

Help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

which country are you from? i know in china, the instances of ec2 cannot be connected unless you use a VPN tool.

Comment: I am from Singapore and the AWS servers are right here. I was able to connect to it earlier, not sure what's wrong now.

Comment: do you open the ssh port in the security setting?

Comment: All TCP ports are allowed. Shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: How do you know that "all TCP ports are allowed"?

Comment: what result does ping return?

Comment: Found the issue. I added Elastic IP to the instance which changed the ssh address. Using the updated address in ssh command fixed it.